# No userData behavior when I have <!DOCTYPE html>?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, local-storage, user-data

I wanted to use HTML5 localStorage in IE9 but it does not support local file system (or file://)
So I fallback to use userData behavior.
But I couldn't get it to work.

After all the testing, I figured out that if I remove the `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of my html, everything works!

Can someone please tell me why?
and if `<!DOCTYPE html>` is a must for HTML5 file?

Comment: Would be helpful if you post a pared-down version of your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 is not an official standard yet. If you set a doctype to a given standard, but use commands which are not part of that standard, or you use a doctype the the browser does not know, browser might not interpret these commands.

Maybe the W3C-validator http://validator.w3.org/ can help you